# For $x^{2}$, how does one show that the $\delta$ which works at $-N$ or $N$ works anywhere else in $[-N,N]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, uniform-continuity

> We know that the function $f(x)=x^{2}$ is continuous at $a$ for all $a$. In other words, if $a$ is any number, then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that, for all $x$, if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|x^{2}-a^{2}|<\epsilon$.
>
> Of course, $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. But $\delta$ also depends on $a$-the $\delta$ that works at $a$ might not work at $b$. Indeed, it's clear that given $\epsilon>0$ there is no one $\delta >0$ that works for all $a$, or even for all positive $a$. In fact, the number $a+\delta/2$ will certainly satisfy $|x-a|<\delta$, but if $a>0$, then
>
> $\biggl|(a+\dfrac{\delta}{2})^{2}-a^{2}\biggr|=\biggl|a\delta + \dfrac{\delta^{2}}{4}\biggr|\ge a\delta$,
>
> and this won't be $< \epsilon$ once $a > \epsilon /\delta$. (This is just an admittedly confusing computational way of saying that $f$ is growing faster and faster!)
>
> On the other hand, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there will be one $\delta >0$ that works for all $a$ in any interval $[-N,N].$ In fact, the $\delta$ which works at $N$ or $-N$ will also work everywhere else in the interval.

So when considering the function $f(x)=x^{2}$, I see how for any $\epsilon >0$, $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{2N}$ works for all $a$ in any interval $[-N,N]$. Now, how would one go about showing that the $\delta$ which works at $N$ or $-N$ also works everywhere else in the interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the $\delta$ that works at $a$ is $\frac \epsilon{|f'(a)|}$.  As $f'(x)=2x, |f'(x)|$ is increasing away from $0$ so the smallest $\delta$ comes at the furthest point from $0$, which is $\pm N$.  The fact that you can find such a $\delta$ says $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous over the interval.  This is important, as it is an assumption in many powerful theorems.

To prove it takes some care.  In fact, $\delta=\frac \epsilon{2N}$ would not be quite small enough if $x$ were allowed to go outside $[-N,N]$.  Let $N=1, \epsilon=0.01$.  Then $f(1)=1$ and you would claim $\delta=\frac \epsilon{f'(1)}=\frac {0.01}2=0.005$ works, but $f(1.005)-f(1)=1.010025-1=0.010025 \gt 0.01$.  The second degree term in the Taylor series kills you.

Aside from that detail, you can say let $a \in [-N,N]$.  Then $|f(a+\delta)-f(a)|=|(a+\delta)^2-a^2|=|2a\delta+\delta^2|\lt |2a\delta|+\delta^2\le 2N\delta+\delta^2$ so if $\delta$ works at $N$ it works at $a$.

Comment: I was wondering what the exact method of deriving $\delta$ at $a$ = $\frac{\epsilon}{|f'(a)|}$ looks like? So far I've done the following: $\lim_{\delta \to 0} \delta|f'(a)|=\lim_{\delta \to 0}|f(a+\delta)-f(a)|<\lim_{\delta \to 0} |2a\delta + \delta^{2}|<\lim_{\delta \to 0} 2N\delta + \delta^{2}$ so $\lim_{\delta \to 0}|f'(a)|<\lim_{\delta \to 0}2N+\delta=2N$ and so $\lim_{\delta \to 0}\dfrac{1}{|f'(a)|}>\dfrac{1}{2N}$

Comment: I showed $\delta=\frac \epsilon{|f'(a)|}$ doesn't work.  It almost works.  It comes from the first term in the Taylor expansion at $a$, but the higher order terms can spoil it, as in my example.  To get a real $\delta$ you need to bound the effect of the higher order terms.

Comment: In order to get a real $\delta$, would I start by setting $\delta <1$?

Comment: Yes, you can put a limit on $\delta$, but I don't think it helps here.  You can say $|f(x+\delta)-f(x)|=|2\delta x + \delta^2|\le 2\delta|x|+1$ but that $+1$ may be larger than $\epsilon$.  What you can do is solve the quadratic inequality $2\delta|x|+\delta^2 \lt \epsilon$ for $\delta$

Comment: using $2\delta|x| + \delta^{2}<\epsilon$, I get $0<2\delta|x| + \delta^{2} + \epsilon$, which means that I get that $\delta = -|x| \pm \sqrt{|x|^{2}-\epsilon}$. So I don't know if I'm on the right track

Comment: You dropped a sign.  It should be $-2\delta|x|$, which changes signs in the solution.  It is the correct approach